# How to do this in jquery style

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code:

```
<p><label for="mobtel">Enter mobile no.:</label><br />
<input id="mobtel" type="text" name="mobtel"/></p>
```

I hide it using jquery with this:

```
$("label[for=mobtel],#mobtel").hide();
```

And now I want now is to display a new label and new input that will look like this:

```
<p><label for="mobtel">Enter verification no.:</label><br />
<input id="verification_no" type="text" name="verification_no"/></p>
```

How can I do this in jquery style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just include both as normal in the HTML, and then hide/show as needed:

```
<p id="mobtelField">
    <label for="mobtel">Enter mobile no.:</label><br />
    <input id="mobtel" type="text" name="mobtel"/>
</p>
<p id="verificationNoField">
    <label for="verification_no">Enter verification no.:</label><br />
    <input id="verification_no" type="text" name="verification_no"/>
</p>
```

and

```
function showVerificationNo(){
    $('#mobtelField').hide();
    $('#verificationNoField').show();
}
function showMobtel(){
    $('#verificationNoField').hide();
    $('#mobtelField').show();
}
```

CSS:

```
#verificationNoField{
    display:none;
}
```

Then call to use:

```
showVerificationNo();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").append('<p><label for="mobtel">Enter verification no.:</label><br />
<input id="verification_no" type="text" name="verification_no"/></p>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K89ZU/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").append('<label for="mobtel">Enter verification no.:</label><br />
<input id="verification_no" type="text" name="verification_no"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to add an invisible element in your HTML:

```
<p><label for="mobtel">Enter mobile no.:</label><br />
<input id="mobtel" type="text" name="mobtel"/></p>
<input id="verification_no" type="text" name="verification_no" style="display:none;"/></p>
```

and then:

```
$("#icatmobtel").hide();
$("#verifion_no").show();
$("label[for=mobtel]").text("Enter verification no.:");
$("label[for=mobtel]").attr("for", "verifion_no");
```

Alternatively you can also add a second label and hide/show it.